# Python3.8 Import Error No module name tqdm found

Tags: python, tqdm

I'm trying to run [this](https://github.com/classner/generating_people) python project on my linux machine. I did setup everything according to the requirement but when I try to run the project with the ./generate.sh executable file I got the following error.

`Import Error: No module name tqdm found`.

Here are the imports exists in file.

```
import os.path as path
import ast
from glob import glob
import signal
import imp
import logging
import time
import numpy as np
import socket
import tqdm
import sys
import click
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.client import timeline
```

I check with `pip3 show tqdm` command it shows me the package detail. I also try to uninstall and install again the project but got no luck.

If i remove the **tqdm** import from the file then it shows me this error.

```
  File "./run.py", line 16, in <module>
    import click
ImportError: No module named click
```

Can someone guide me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are importing it wrong, from tqdm docs:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
```

I've checked it for both python2 and 3 and this is the way to use it.

The project you are trying to use at least 3 years old, so maybe things have changed since then, so if it wont work for you even with proper import statement you can simply remove it.

Every loop working with tqdm will work without it as well.
For example:

```
from tqdm import tqdm

for i in tqdm(range(10000)):
    pass
```

is the same as:

```
for i in range(10000)):
    pass
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Yes you're right the project is 3 years old and that is the problem. Before when I try to run the project with Python 2.7 on which this project is build I got import error but when I run the project with Python 3.8 it successfully runs. Although there are other errors occurred which I'm trying to resolve.